# Change English Number To Persian Numbers in Text Swift,IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Hi How can i replace english numbers with persian numbers in string in IOS Swift

```
"This is a english text with this numbers 09122223231 34322 "
```

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't change your question completely. Instead ask a new question. What you did invalidates all answers to this point and works against Stack Overflow's idea to provide a big repository of questions with answers (because you just removed a question essentially). I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 8):

Replace the numbers in a string with its eq in persian

```
func convertToPersian(inputStr:String)-> String {
    let numbersDictionary : Dictionary = ["0" : "۰","1" : "۱", "2" : "۲", "3" : "۳", "4" : "۴", "5" : "۵", "6" : "۶", "7" : "۷", "8" : "۸", "9" : "۹"]
    var str : String = inputStr

    for (key,value) in numbersDictionary {
        str =  str.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
    }

    return str
}
```

This Change "farshad i think number 11 33 42 3343 is fit you" to "farshad i think number ۱۱ ۳۳ ۴۲ ۳۳۴۳ is fit you"

if your text is a string with only number chars you can use this method :

```
func convertEngNumToPersianNum(inputStr:String)->String{
    let format = NumberFormatter()
    format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    let number =   format.number(from: inputStr)
    let faNumber = format.string(from: number!)
    return faNumber!
}
```

then you can convert "091233344455" to "۰۹۱۲۳۳۳۴۴۴۵۵"

also you can write a extension for String to simplify usage something like this

SWIFT 3

```
    extension String {
    func convertEngNumToPersianNum()->String{
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        let number =   format.number(from: self)

        let faNumber = format.string(from: number!)
        return faNumber!

    }
    func convertToPersian()-> String {
        let numbersDictionary : Dictionary = ["0" : "۰","1" : "۱", "2" : "۲", "3" : "۳", "4" : "۴", "5" : "۵", "6" : "۶", "7" : "۷", "8" : "۸", "9" : "۹"]
        var str : String = self

        for (key,value) in numbersDictionary {
            str =  str.replacingOccurrences(of: key, with: value)
        }

        return str
    } 
}
```

Some times you want convert Number To Toman/Rial...
you can use this To Convert Number To Currency

```
  extension Int {
    var asCurrency:String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        formatter.currencySymbol=""
        if(self != 0)        {
            return  ("\(formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!) تومان"
        }
        else{
            return ""
        }
    }
 }
```

USAGE :

```
"091233344455".convertEngNumToPersianNum()  //"۰۹۱۲۳۳۳۴۴۴۵۵"

"091233344455".convertToPersian()  //"۰۹۱۲۳۳۳۴۴۴۵۵"

"به نظر من 11 33 42 3343 عدد خوبیه".convertToPersian() //به نظر من۱۱ ۳۳ ۴۲ ۳۳۴۳ عدد خوبیه

111222333.asCurrency //۱۱۱،۲۲۲،۳۳۳ تومان
```

Answer (score 2):

A small function to convert english number to persian:-

```
func convertEngNumToPersianNum(num: String)->String{
    //let number = NSNumber(value: Int(num)!)
    let format = NumberFormatter()
    format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    let number =   format.number(from: num)
    let faNumber = format.string(from: number!)
    return faNumber!

}
let string = "This is a english text with this numbers 09122223231 34322 "
if let number = Int(string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()) {
 let perNum = convertEngNumToPersianNum(num: String(number))
    print(perNum)
}
```

**Working proof:-** 
[image]